# Javascript Events does not work with Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I got an article : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_js_events.htm

I working with **ionic 4**

I would like to use many of this even but no one works.
and mainly I would like to trigger the action sheet by sliding my finger from the bottom of the screen to top

Someone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/) to use certain mouse events/gestures to your Ionic 4 app (easily). It can recognise actions like pan, pinch, press, rotate, swipe etc and tap gesture recognition. **hammer.js** is based on browser mouse/touch events.

Read more in this article https://medium.com/madewithply/ionic-4-long-press-gestures-96cf1e44098b and watch this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdORJC-J1gg which shows how to setup hammer.js gestures in Ionic 4 .

Comment: Thank for this info